# PlayOnLinux Photoshop CS6 Crash

Tags: 14.04, photoshop

Photoshop CS6 crashes while im trying to create new image.

I get this error

wine: Unhandled exception 0xc06d007e in thread 9 at address 0x7b83bfee (thread 0009), starting debugger...
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d

Comment: Have you tried selecting Wine to run on a different version of Windows(i.e, select Windows7, instead of 8..)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I did the following steps and its working now:

1. Open `PlayOnLinux`.
2. Click on `Photoshop` in right pane.
3. Click on `Configure` button.
4. Go to `Install Components` tab.
5. Find `atmlib` in the list.
6. Click on `Install`.
7. After installation restart photoshop.

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: only worked for me one times